# Why does XDocument.Save create duplicate nodes?

Tags: xml, vb.net

Below is code I'm using to write xml to a file via an XDocument object

```
   Dim rg As New ReportGenerated(msMemberIDTxt, msMemberGroupIDTxt, msAllInd, sFileName, ReportNameTxt,
                                              msFrequencyCde, sSFTPError)
            Dim xmlString As String = xml.DocumentElement.OuterXml
            Dim xdoc As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(xmlString)

            Try

                If File.Exists(filepath) Then
                    File.Delete(filepath)
                End If
                xdoc.Save(filepath)
```

Below is a snippet of the xml string being parsed. Note that I am using the outerXml which works fine.

```
<CollisionExtract xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://titan.safety.state.tn.us/titan/Public/docs/titancrashextract.xsd">
  <Collision>
    <MstrRecNbrTxt>102346969</MstrRecNbrTxt>
    <CollisionDte>2019-12-11T00:00:00Z</CollisionDte>
    <CollisionTimeUnknownInd>N</CollisionTimeUnknownInd>   
    <Unit>
      <MstrRecNbrTxt>102346969</MstrRecNbrTxt>
      <UnitIdNmb>1</UnitIdNmb>      
      <VINTxt>12121212121212121</VINTxt>
      <CommercialUnit>
        <MstrRecNbrTxt>102346969</MstrRecNbrTxt>
        <UnitIDNmb>1</UnitIDNmb>       
        </CommercialUnitHazMat>
      </CommercialUnit>      
  </Collision>
</CollisionExtract>
```

After I save write the xdocument to a file, and open the file, I get the following. Long story short, the file writing process is duplicating the CollisionExtract node for some reason, and I have no idea why it would take a perfectly well parsed xml string and do that.

```
<CollisionExtract xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://titan.safety.state.tn.us/titan/Public/docs/titancrashextract.xsd">
  <Collision>
    <MstrRecNbrTxt>102346969</MstrRecNbrTxt>
    <CollisionDte>2019-12-11T00:00:00Z</CollisionDte>
    <CollisionTimeUnknownInd>N</CollisionTimeUnknownInd>   
    <Unit>
      <MstrRecNbrTxt>102346969</MstrRecNbrTxt>
      <UnitIdNmb>1</UnitIdNmb>      
      <VINTxt>12121212121212121</VINTxt>
      <CommercialUnit>
        <MstrRecNbrTxt>102346969</MstrRecNbrTxt>
        <UnitIDNmb>1</UnitIDNmb>       
        </CommercialUnitHazMat>
      </CommercialUnit>      
  </Collision>
</CollisionExtract><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><CollisionExtract xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://titan.safety.state.tn.us/titan/Public/docs/titancrashextract.xsd"><Collision><MstrRecNbrTxt>102346969</MstrRecNbrTxt><CollisionDte>2019-12-11T00:00:00Z</CollisionDte><CollisionTimeUnknownInd>N</CollisionTimeUnknownInd><NbrUnitsNmb>1</NbrUnitsNmb><NbrFatalitiesNmb>0</NbrFatalitiesNmb><NbrInjuredNmb>2</NbrInjuredNmb><NbrNonInjuredNmb>0</NbrNonInjuredNmb><NbrMotoristsNmb>1</NbrMotoristsNmb><NbrNonMotoristsNmb>1</NbrNonMotoristsNmb><AgencyOriTxt>019013C</Collision></CollisionExtract>
```

Comment: Does `MsgBox(xmlString)` display the correct string?

Comment: It looks a bit like two separate procedures wrote XML to the same file in append mode. Can you check for this?

Comment: The two strings must be in the outerXml.  You aren't seeing it because it is either on a different line or there are a lot of white spaces.  When you are using XDocument the white spaces are getting removed so you see the duplicate data.